# Why List remains unchanged?

Tags: java, nio

I try to create a small application that uses file walker to recursively read contents of specified place of filesystem. I have this code:

```
/* Imports here */

public class App {

    private static Scanner inp;
    public static List<Node> Tree = new ArrayList<Node>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String FFiles;

        System.out.print("Enter root directory: ");
        inp = new Scanner(System.in);

        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();
        Path rootPath = fileSystem.getPath(inp.nextLine());

        FileVisitor<Path> simpleFileVisitor = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
              public Path VisitedDirectory = rootPath;
              public List<Node> files = new ArrayList<Node>();


              @Override
              public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                if (dir != VisitedDirectory) {
                    Node directory = new Node(dir.getFileName().toString(), "directory", files, dir.toString());
                    files.add(directory);
                    Node VisDirectory = new Node(VisitedDirectory.getFileName().toString(), "directory", files, dir.toString());
                    Tree.add(VisDirectory);

                    files.clear();
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
              }

              @Override
              public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path visitedFile,BasicFileAttributes fileAttributes) throws IOException {
                Node file = new Node(visitedFile.getFileName().toString(), "file", null, visitedFile.toString());
                files.add(file);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
              }
        };



        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(rootPath, simpleFileVisitor);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (Node n : Tree) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
```

And here's the question: Why it reads (shows) only directories?
P.S Node class is just a couple of variables and declared like so:

```
public class Node {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node [path=" + path + "]";
    }

    public String name;
    public String path;
    public  String type;
    public List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    public Node(String name, String type, List<Node> children, String path) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.children = children;
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

Comment: Place a breakpoint in the visitFile method. Check if execution hits it. Also in visit dir you add to Tree list. In visit file you don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are making a big mess with the `files` list. You only ever create a single instance. Thus your `new Node(VisitedDirectory.getFileName().toString(), "directory", files, dir.toString())` doesn't actually copy the files list but merely stores a reference. Your `files.clear()` call will clear all files lists you have. This is why only the nodes you add to `Tree` will ever survive.

And please rename `Tree` to lowercase. This way one thinks `Tree.add()` invokes a static method on the `Tree` class.